# AWS redshift join with a function returns an error

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to join two different tables by using a left function - for reference (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LEFT.html) And it throws an error saying "invalid operation" i wish the error message was a little more helpful. If i remove the left function then it works but i need to make it work with a function as i didn't see any limitations on docs.. I am not sure why it doesn't work with a function as  Any advice on how to solve it?

```
select id from state
LEFT JOIN city c ON lower(left(c.segmentation_name::text, '-4'::integer)) = lower(state.name::text)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just asking - why casting to `text`?  it's not a type which is normally used - it's there for legacy support of leader-node Postgres tables.  Also, it's bizzare to write '-4'::integer - just write -4.  Also also, as the answer says, it's a positive value you pass here, not a negative.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all but the last four characters, then use:

```
from state s left join
     city c 
     on substring(lower(c.segmentation_name::text), 1, len(c.segmentation_name::text) - 4) = lower(state.name::text)
```

The conversions to `text` look really awkward.  Perhaps this is sufficient:

```
from state s left join
     city c 
     on substring(lower(c.segmentation_name), 1, len(c.segmentation_name) - 4) = lower(state.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

[left](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LEFT.html) supports only positive integers as a second argument. Try `right(c.segmentation_name::text, 4)` instead.